Can TreeItem be used in ViewModel in MVVM in JavaFX?
I am creating TreeView using MVVM pattern in JavaFX. And I can't understand if I should use TreeItem in ModelView, for example
class MyViewModel {
   private final TreeItem<Model> rootItem = ...;
}

Or TreeItem should be used only in View.
Could anyone say, where TreeItem is used in MVVM pattern?

TreeItem is a funny, in between, thing.  It's not a Node, but it responds to some Events and can contain Nodes.  That means it's more than just data.
Generally speaking, in MVVM, the ViewModel contains the Presentation Data, and the Presentation Data should be in a form suitable for binding in the View.  In JavaFX that means Observables and ObservableLists.  So, there is some implied "exposure" of the Presentation Data to the nature of the View, but only that it's a GUI in JavaFX.
If you have a StringProperty in your Presentation Data, there's still no way to know how the View is going to use it.  It could bind to the textProperty() of a Label, a TextField, a CheckBox or a TextArea or a Text.  A StringProperty could be thought of as an Observable primitive type.
However, a TreeItem implies a TreeView in the View.  There's not much else you can do with it.  And what if there's some kind of special Node that you want to put in the the TreeItem via setGraphic()?  You absolutely cannot go around creating Nodes in your ViewModel.
Always, the big question with MVVM (or MVC) is, "Could I change the internal implementation of this component without affecting the other components?".  The answer is supposed to always be "Yes!", and if not, then you've messed up the MVVM/MVC implementation.
So, if you have an ObservableList<TreeItem> in your Presentation Data in your ViewModel, can you change the implementation of the View without impacting the ViewModel?  Not if you replace the TreeView with something else.  Not even if you change the nature or structure of the TreeView.  You are tied to the implementation of the View and the TreeView.
On the other hand, you'll have to be careful that whatever structure that you do create in the Presentation Data to hold the information for the TreeView allows the View to transform that data into TreeItems without requiring so much work that it crosses the line into "Business Logic", which belongs in the Model.
This means that you are going to have to implement the parent <--> child relationships in your data in some generic way, and the code in the View will need to be able to interpret it to create TreeItems.
So the short answer is, "No, you shouldn't put TreeItems in your ViewModel".
